# Estimote API integration

Tags: php, api, ibeacon, estimote, beacon

so i've been trying to integrate Estimote API to bring the beacons list to my personal CMS, i'm encountering with the problem that i get "Unauthorised" message i have read through the Api docs and the General - Authorization is the one that i can since i'm bringing the beacons that are in my cloud account, theres an example on a curl request that i can get the list of beacons by doing this:

```
curl -u app_0a1b2c3d4e:0a1b2c3d4e5f6a7b8c9d0e1f2a3b4c5d \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' \
     https://cloud.estimote.com/v1/beacons
```

The problem is that i have been trying to do that and it says that In general i should use App ID and App Token to authorise my requests

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$app_id = "appid";
$token = "token";
$ch = curl_init('https://cloud.estimote.com/v1/beacons?appid='.$appId.'&apptoken='.$token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

any ideas on what am i doing wrong? 
https://cloud.estimote.com/docs/#api-Beacons-GetBeacons

Comment: Do you have an appid and app token ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix Shaddix yes it's register in my estimote cloud account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to send post fields with a get request.

You can remove this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);`

In the documentation https://cloud.estimote.com/docs/#api-General-Authorization it says that you need to send your appid as username and token as password. In curl you have that option.

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cloud.estimote.com/v1/beacons');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$appid:$token");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: the problem is that i have tried this way and i'm still getting the "Unauthorized" response. @Vasil Shaddix

Comment: can you give us the api documentation for this request ?

Comment: yes i just edited the post at the end of the post there are the links to the doc! @Vasil Shaddix

Comment: i read the documentation and you have it wrong, edited my answer

Comment: oh dude i didn't know about the CURLOPT_USERPWD, it finally work! thank you so much! @Vasil Shaddix